# Makefile can't find include path

Tags: makefile

My folder structure is like below

```
/Myapp/main.c  
/Myapp/f1.c  
/Myapp/f1.h  
/Myapp/Makefile
```

and my Makefile contest is

```
CC = gcc
main: main.o f1.o
    $(CC) -o main main.o f1.o
main.o: main.c f1.h
f1.o: f1.c f1.h
```

I run the makefile at directory Myapp, and it works fine

BUT...when I move f1.h to a include folder like this:

```
/Myapp/main.c  
/Myapp/f1.c  
/Myapp/Makefile  
/Myapp/include/f1.h
```

and Makefile add include path

```
CC = gcc
INCLUDE = ./include/
main: main.o f1.o
    $(CC) -I$(INCLUDE) -o main main.o f1.o
main.o: main.c f1.h
f1.o: f1.c f1.h
```

it will show: make: *** No rule to make target `f1.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.

This confuse me for a while.
After searching the relative question still can't resolve this simple problem
(I guess this is might be a relative dir problem, right?)
Thanks for help.

Comment: Just to clarify: by adding `-I$(INCLUDE)` to your recipe you've told _your compiler_ how to find the header files.  But `make` is not your compiler and it doesn't parse compiler options.  `make` needs to be able to find (or know how to build) any file listed as a prerequisite, so you have to tell _make_ how to find the header files.  There are various ways to do that, one of which is to use the pathname to the header file as the prerequisite as suggested by the answers here.

Comment: Thanks for help to understand the difference between make and gcc.
I appreciate your help very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
main.o: main.c f1.h
f1.o: f1.c f1.h
```

to

```
main.o: main.c $(INCLUDE)f1.h
    $(CC) -c -o main.o main.c -I$(INCLUDE)
f1.o: f1.c $(INCLUDE)f1.h
    $(CC) -c -o f1.o f1.c -I$(INCLUDE)
```

you need to change path for f1.h related, add "include" for it

Comment: Thanks for advice. this works. I'll try to improve the script flow and make it more automatically.

Comment: It's a kind of weird the -I option not really work perfectly. maybe I need study makefile syntax more.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way avoiding lists of `-I` arguments is to make all `#include` directives specify files relative to the Makefile's directory. E.g. in main.c and f1.c you write

```
#include "include/f1.h"
```

and in your Makefile

```
main.o: main.c include/f1.h
    ...
f1.o: f1.c include/f1.h
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Makerules work recursively. When resolving *main* make first resolves all it's dependencies in the given order. So it does:

1. Trying to make rule main: Checking dependencies.
2. First dependency: main.o, not yet done, so pause and do this now
3. Trying to make rule main.o: Checking dependencies.
4. First dependency: main.c, not yet done.
5. Trying to make rule main.c. No rule found. Cheking if file exists. file found. Dependency resolved, back to main.o
6. second dependency: f1.h, not done yet.
7. Trying to make rule f1.h. No rule found. Checking if file exists. Not found, aborting, error.

So the problem isn't that the rule *main* doesn't know where f1.h is, but *main.o*
The simplest way, if you want to keep your rules would be to just change the rule main.o to
`main.o: main.c $(INCLUDE)f1.h`

Comment: same for f1.o, of course :)

Comment: Thanks for explain the flow. This works to me